# Get data from Yahoo! Finance to R

Tags: r

I am trying to get data from Yahoo! Finance to R

I've installed quantmod like that:

```
install.packages("quantmod", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

But when I try this:

```
getQuote("QQQQ;SPY", what=yahooQF("Last Trade (Price Only)"))
```

I see:

```
Error in download.file(paste("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?
s=",  : 
cannot open URL 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?
s=QQQQ+SPY&f=d1t1l1'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(paste("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=",  :
URL 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?
s=QQQQ+SPY&f=d1t1l1': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'
```

Comment: getSymbols("YHOO",src="google") # from google finance ---------
                               
financegetSymbols("GOOG",src="yahoo")  # from yahoo finance ------
                              
https://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/

Comment: @ Andryas Waurzenczak. Thanks. It works! How to get not daily quotes?

Comment: Use functions, to.weekly , to.year see the link in my first comment.

Comment: @ Andryas Waurzenczak Thanks again!

Comment: @Andryas Waurzenczak, Is something wrong with GOOGL method now?

Comment: I can't receive data by getSymbols("GOOGL",src="google")

Comment: but yesterday I can

Comment: cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=GOOGL&startdate=Jan+01,+2007&enddate=Mar+16,+2018&output=csv': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'

Answer (score 1):

To answer the specific question asked:

```
getSymbols("QQQ;SPY", from="1997-12-31", src='yahoo')
```

works just fine - you get two `xts` series, QQQ and SPY (note that [QQQQ is *"dead"* and replaced with QQQ](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/qqq.asp)), with 6 columns `Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close`, `Volume`, `Adjusted`.
It looks like you only want the close? If so, you can get just that series with

```
Cl(QQQ)
```

If you don't like auto-assignment, you can use

```
qqq.data <- getSymbols("QQQ", auto.assign=FALSE, from="1997-12-31", src='yahoo')
```

to assign the downloaded data to a variable of your choice. Note that most people would probably be interested in the adjusted price instead, if so, you can select it with

```
Ad(QQQ)
```

Finally, indeed, as pointed out, google finance no longer provides data through its API.

Answer (score 0):

`getSymbols("AAPL",src="google")` has been deprecated.

`Error: ‘getSymbols.google’ is defunct.
Google Finance stopped providing data in March, 2018.
You could try setting src = "yahoo" instead.
See help("Defunct") and help("quantmod-defunct")`

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. This is useful information. Although, it doesn't answer the OP's question and would have been better suited as a comment.