# Download failed while using quantmod function getSymbols in For loop

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to get data for the 1632 stocks that comprise the NSE index in India using the `quantmod` package. I am able to download stocks individually; however, when I loop over all the stocks, I am getting a timeout. How do I loop the `getSymbols` function to download the desire data?

Following error is reported:

> Error: '20MICRONS.NS' download failed after two attempts. Error message:
>   HTTP error 404. 
>   5.
>   stop(Symbols.name, " download failed after two attempts. Error", 
>       " message:\n", attr(dl, "condition")$message, call. = FALSE) 
>   4.
>   getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "'20MICRONS.NS'", env = , 
>       verbose = FALSE, warnings = TRUE, auto.assign = TRUE) 
>   3.
>   do.call(paste("getSymbols.", symbol.source, sep = ""), list(Symbols = current.symbols, 
>       env = env, verbose = verbose, warnings = warnings, auto.assign = auto.assign, 
>       ...))
>   2.
>   getSymbols(as.character(x), src = "yahoo") 
>   1.
>   f(Symbol[i])

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="C:/Documents/EQUITY_L.csv", header=TRUE)
Symbol <- MyData$SYMBOL

f <- function(x) { getSymbols(as.character(x), src='yahoo') }
for (i in 1:1632) { f(Symbol[i]) }
```

Comment: The triple quote around `20MICRONS.NS` in the error message looks suspicious.  I had no problem running `quantmod::getSymbols("20MICRONS.NS")` on my machine just now.  If you think you a pause between downloads would help, you can add a two second pause in each iteration of your loop with `Sys.sleep(2)`.  To dig in further, I would need to see what's in the "Equity_L.csv" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I see...

First download Symbols from: 
https://www.nseindia.com/corporates/content/securities_info.htm
It's the first file listed on the page.

It appears each symbol from the NSE file needs to add an ".NS" suffix. That's why you can download the equities individually, but it fails when you pass the Symbol column of your file to `getSymbols`.

I'd also create a new environment to dump every stock into and keep your global environment manageable.

Finally, pass `NSE_Symbols` to quantmods `getSymbols` function for daily data.
I Like to use `sapply` coupled with `try` so that if you hit a bad symbol,
the `HTTP error 404` won't halt the remaining symbols from downloading.

```
EQUITY_L <- read.csv("~/R/stack-overflow/data/EQUITY_L.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

NSE_Symbols <- paste0(EQUITY_L$SYMBOL,".NS")

NSE_stocks <- new.env() 

library(quantmod)
sapply(NSE_Symbols, function(x){try(getSymbols(x, env=NSE_stocks), silent=TRUE)})
```

Next, test and find out which symbols didn't download. I was able to get all but 17.

```
length(NSE_Symbols[!(NSE_Symbols %in% names(NSE_stocks))])
[1] 17

NSE_Symbols[!(NSE_Symbols %in% names(NSE_stocks))]
[1] "3PLAND.NS"     "BHAGYANGR.NS"  "CHEMFAB.NS"    "ELECTROSL.NS"  "GANGESSECU.NS" 
[6] "GMMPFAUDLR.NS" "GUJRAFFIA.NS"  "HBSL.NS"       "KALYANI.NS"    "MAGADSUGAR.NS" 
[11] "MANAKCOAT.NS"  "MCDOWELL-N.NS" "NIRAJISPAT.NS" "PALASHSECU.NS" "SIGIND.NS"
[16]"SPTL.NS"       "SUBCAPCITY.NS"
```

The symbols which downloaded succesfully will be neatly contained in the `NSE_stocks` environment.

Good luck,

[r](/questions/tagged/r)[quantmod](/questions/tagged/quantmod)

Comment: Bonus: If you just need the closing price, you can bring the securities back into the global environment as single xts object with this: `NSE_xts <- do.call(merge, eapply(NSE_stocks, Ad))`

Comment: @JustinThank you but the code is not serving the purpose. I get the same missing Symbols as you do,however, this is only a string and not the actual xts object.  I edited the paste function to NSE_Symbols <- paste0("'",MyData$SYMBOL,".NS'") and still it is not working.

Comment: If you get the same missing symbols then that means you downloaded all equities except 17, which is what the string reports. The rest of the equities are in the `NSE_stocks` environment. See my comment above your on how to bring them into your global environment.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes! the variable NSE_xts holds the data for all the closing prices.  I am new to coding and the environment and do.call definitely add value.

Comment: Yes do.call and environments are a good combination. `do.call` especially is very useful, I'd study the documentation for that in depth, as well as that of `sapply`. In addition, search stack overflow for other examples which use those functions. Good luck!

Comment: please let me know how do I bring the High, low and volume price into the global environment. Thanks